# Get Sum of a Specific Column on Editing a Cell in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, sum, jtable, listener

I am trying to get the sum of column 4 on typing/editing the value on column 4. Immediately i change the figure i.e as i type on any row of column 4 it should change my sum which i set on a jTextField.

I have tried TableModelListener and ListSelectionListener but it has not worked efficiently because i have to click on the row for it to get the summary.

```
jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt){
    float sum = 0;
    int[] rows = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
    for(int i=0;i<jTable1.getRowCount();i++){
    try{
    sum = sum + 
Float.parseFloat(jTable1.getValueAt(rows[i],4).toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    continue;
    }
    }
    jTextField15.setText(Float.toString(sum));
    getsummaries();
    }
});
```

Immediately i change the value on Column 4 i would like it ot autosum on jTextField15.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table.

Comment: Basically on typing on column 4 i want it to immediately autosum on my jtextfield. In which was is this possible?

Comment: Minus one for ignoring my advice. I can remove it on [edit] to add a MCVE. Oh, and a close vote because I forgot before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it has not worked efficiently because i have to click on the row for it to get the summary.

The model is only updated when the cell loses focus because that is when the value you are typing is saved to the model. This is because you could start typing numbers and then use the "escape" key to cancel the editing.

If you really want to update the total as the user types into the editor, then instead of using a TableModelListener, you will need to add a `DocumentListener` to the text field used by the editor:

```
DefaultCellEditor editor = (DefaultCellEditor)table.getDefaultEditor(Integer.class);
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getComponent();
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(...);
```

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Listening For Changes on a Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more information and examples.

Of course if you do this, you will also need to handle the case when the editor is cancelled. So you will also need to add a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JTable` and listen for `tableCellEditor` property change.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet gotten a solution to this yet. On typing on JTable it's difficult to record the sum. A workaround would be to create a button and it computes the total on the jTextField.

Comment: This does not look like an answer, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Have the same problem?". Did you actually try the work-around? With what result?

Comment: This works great but i didn't want to include a button instead for it to autosum on typing